# Symfony 2.8 Twig extension based on current logged user

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

What I want to do is show logged user only content that he has access to.

First thing I was doing  **access_control** in **security.yml** & redirect but i must do at least 30 deferent accounts;/

Next i create twig extension that will connect to DB and get current logged user specific settings - 
access to panels. Is this good way?

The problem is

```
$user = $this->getUser()->getId();
$currentUser = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($user);
```

It will not work, Blank page appears in dev env

But when i put 1

```
$currentUser = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find(1);
```

& 1 is user id everything is ok.

**services.yml**

```
    app.twig.users_extension:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\Extension\AccesExtension
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager","@security.token_storage"]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

**Twig Extension**

```
class AccesExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

protected $em;
protected $tokenStorage;


public function __construct(EntityManager $em, TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}

public function getUser()
{
    return $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
}

public function getGlobals()
{
    $user = $this->getUser()->getId();
    $currentUser = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($user);
    return array (
        "acces" => $currentUser,
    );
}

public function getName()
{
    return "AppBundle:AccesExtension ";
}
```

}

Comment: "Didn't work" is a bit vague.  But normally you would use some sort of voter system for this sort of thing.

Comment: More specifically: if I put $currentUser = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find(**1**); & **1 is Id of user** everything is ok, but as is it now symfony in very slow & profiler disapear without any bug, only blank page come up.

Comment: Have a look at [security voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people in the comments already told you, you can use [security voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html).

Here is a [simple tutorial](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-voters/voters) with video/text that explains the use of voters and also how to use them in twig, this should help you with the problem you have.